# Radiator leaks after replacing radiator & water pump

Tags: radiator

Leaking a cupful of radiator fluid daily still after replacing the radiator then later the water pump! What else could it be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing coolant fast after just fixing radiator](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25786/losing-coolant-fast-after-just-fixing-radiator)

Comment: Cracked block, hoses, heater core... There are other parts to your cooling system.

Comment: Is the fluid leaking onto the ground or is it just completely dissapearing?  Make/model/year of vehicle?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is the radiator? You don't tell us the car... But on mine, they are known to split the coolant reservoir and it only leaks when hot which means the hot fluid evaporates and leave very little residue. You need to check all the hoses, connections and the reservoir for any signs of leaks.